# Why is my github repository not listed on my homepage?

Tags: github

I created this repo: https://github.com/meltzerj/Dreamstill that appears on my profile but not on the home page where it says "Your Repositories". Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a simple caching issue (as in "it will be updated soon").
If not, report it like in [this (older) issue](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/372-public-repo-missing-from-my-your-repositories-list).